# (ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, es6-modules

I have a error on importing esm:

```
requiere = require(module);
module.exports = require('./bot'); // this 2 line inside index.js
```

This is try open my `bot.js`; but I got an error:

> ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
> This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/Users/vladimirlevcenko/MavenBot/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.